# `[Function]` and `[Function: Object]` - what is difference?

Tags: node.js

```
var Cls = function(){}
var inst = new Cls()
var obj = {}

console.log(inst.constructor)
console.log(obj.constructor)
```

outputs:

```
[Function]
[Function: Object]
```

What is difference between `[Function]` and `[Function: Object]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can have an immutable *name* (which is independent of the name of any variable that might refer to the function). A function's name (if it has one) is part of its definition:

```
function NAME () { ... }
```

When Node's `console.log` logs a function, the output will include the function's name, if it has one.

Here, `obj.constructor` is the `Object` constructor, which happens to have the name `Object` (i.e., it is defined by `function Object() { ... }`). Your `Cls` function, however, does not have a name (i.e., it is defined by an anonymous function `function() { }`). If you give that function a name, you will see it reported by `console.log`:

```
var Cls = function thisIsTheNameOfCls(){}
var inst = new Cls()
var obj = {}

console.log(inst.constructor)
console.log(obj.constructor)
```

This produces the output:

```
[Function: thisIsTheNameOfCls]
[Function: Object]
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Javascript doesn't have classes, it has functions that can be instantiated. `var Cls` is an anonymous function; `Object` is a named function.

---

Long answer:

Javascript functions can be instantiated to create objects, similarly to how classes can be instantiated in other formal object oriented languages.

That being said, what you're seeing is the result of your use of an anonymous function.

The first line of output simply shows the constructor for `inst` is a function. It doesn't have a name, therefore no name is shown; it is *anonymous*.

The second line is showing it was created from the `Object` function.

Here are two variations to better show my point:

```
var Cls = function Cls(){};
var inst = new Cls();
```

should now accurately show

```
[Function: Cls]
```

As well, you can also do

```
var obj = new Object();
```

which is similar to

```
var obj = {}
```